# Is there a quick way to write static a href links? HTML

Tags: static, href, html

I have a html page where i list the out static links to my photos,
I have to list them out line by line and change the number i.e. the name of the photos. It's a good thing that the numbers are in running order and the jpg files are named with just 4 digit numbers. For e.g. :

```
<a href=pics/0001.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/0001.jpg></a>
<a href=pics/0002.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/0001.jpg></a>
<a href=pics/0003.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/0001.jpg></a>
<a href=pics/0004.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/0001.jpg></a>
<a href=pics/0005.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/0001.jpg></a>
...
<a href=pics/1999.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/1999.jpg></a>
```

is there a more elegant way to do this? or is manually typing in the 0001.jpg to 1999.jpg the only way? Is there a perl/python script to do help write static html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cbcak/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var str = '';
    for (var i=1;i<=1999;i++) {
        var num = zeroFill(i, 4);
        str += '<a href=pics/'+num+'.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/'+num+'.jpg></a>'+"\n";
    }
    $('pre').text(str);

    function zeroFill( number, width )
    {
     width -= number.toString().length;
      if ( width > 0 )
     {
       return new Array( width + (/\./.test( number ) ? 2 : 1) ).join( '0' ) + number;
     }
     return number + ""; // always return a string
  }
});
</script>
<pre></pre>​
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use javascript to dynamically generate them, but you still have to provide the href and src in a source location (file)

Otherwise, your looking at .NET, Java, php, or some other web scripting language which can read the images from a database or xml file

I'm sure there are other options, just not thinking of them at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this python 3 script:

```
for d in range(2000):
    print("<a href=pics/" + str(d).zfill(4) + ".jpg target=blank><img src=pics/" + str(d).zfill(4)+ ".jpg></a>" )
```

Running will produce your expected output (`<a href=pics/xxxx.jpg target=blank><img src=pics/xxxx.jpg></a>`
), which you can just copy and paste into your html file.

Comment: sounds good but that's sort of brute-forcing the prints and copy and paste into my html file. Maybe there is a solution out there for this, some sort of dynamic javascript perhaps.

Comment: I'll edit in a javascript version.  Just give me a few minutes.  Edit: Darn, ifunk beat me to it.